# ReactJS: State only updates every second click

Tags: reactjs, state, use-state

I´m quite new to React and have got the following simple Component:

```
import { useState } from "react";

const Counter = () => {
  let [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  const countUp = () => {
    console.log(counter);
    setCounter(counter++);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button onClick={countUp}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Counter;
```

I initialize the state with 0 and want to count up on every click on the button. This works, but only when I click twice. The first click does not affect the number.

I thought I might solve it with like this:

```
setCounter((counter) => {
  counter++;
});
```

But this even results in undefined. Can someone help me? Why does this happend and how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should avoid mutating state in React. As it is bad practice. Write it like this:

```js
const Counter = () => {
  let [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(0);

  const countUp = () => {
    console.log(counter);
    setCounter(counter + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{counter}</p>
      <button onClick={countUp}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};

// export default Counter;

ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: ok, thank you. Coming from vue this kind of syntax felt quite intuitive, good to know in React this is different :-)

Answer (score 2):

It's not a react issue. It has to do with the way you increment. Instead of `counter++`, try with `++counter`. I invite you to read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment) to learn more about the difference between postfix increment and prefix increment.

As @Konstantin rightly pointed out, there's another problem, you should not mutate state directly. But at least it should answer your question as to why it occurred every two second clicks.

[Unary Operators in JavaScript](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-unary-operators/)

Comment: State should not be mutated in React.

Comment: @KonstantinModin yep, you're right, there's also that. Thanks for pointing that out.